# Show text in android with native c++ without 3rd party

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am searching for a possibility to show text without 3rd party libraries (e.g. freetype) to show text in native c++ on Android. (By the way... I am no Shader expert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using OpenGL ES 2 or above, you will need to write a very basic shader.  Even if all it does is read the texture.  There should be enough samples on Github to find something basic.  Or checkout Shadertoy.com.

What you want is a Bitmap font.  Try a font generator like this one, read in the font descriptor, set the image plane as the texture and draw strings by grabbing the source rects. http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/

LibGDX also has a font generator and even though it's written in Java, the shaders are embedded in the code for rendering.

Even if you did use freetype or stb_truetype, you would still only get images planes and character descriptors (glyph source rects).  You would still need to do a lot of font rendering.

Check stb_trutype for some basic examples, I think they are very minimal as far as writing shaders and composing strings into geometry.